# How do I run a test for an array of json objects sent through the request?

Tags: laravel, validation, phpunit

I'm passing an array of json objects through the request to be validated in the controller:

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'situation' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    $emotions= ['data' => $request->input('emotions')];
    

    $emotionsValidation = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($emotions, [
        'data.*.id' => 'integer|between:1,70',
        'data.*.intensity' => 'integer|between:0,100',
        'data.*.new_intensity' => 'integer|between:0,100'
    ]);

    
    if($emotionsValidation->fails()) {
        
        return response(['error' => 'There was a problem with the emotions you submitted.'],422);
    }

    $emotions= ['data' => $request->input('emotions')];
    

    $emotionsValidation = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($emotions, [
        'data.*.id' => 'integer|between:1,70',
        'data.*.intensity' => 'integer|between:0,100',
        'data.*.new_intensity' => 'integer|between:0,100'
    ]);

    
    if($emotionsValidation->fails()) {
        return response(['error' => 'There was a problem with the emotions you submitted.'],422);
    }
    
    //Return record resource
}
```

The validation works normally, but the test isn't passing like it should be:

**Test**

```
/** @test */
public function a_records_json_emotions_must_be_integers()
{
    $this->actingAs($creator = factory('App\User')->create());

    $thought = [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'situation' => 'A situation',
        'emotions' => json_decode("[{'id': 2000, 'intensity': 100, 'new_intensity': 20}]")
    ];

    //dd(json_encode("[{'id': 2000, 'intensity': 100, 'new_intensity': 20}]"));
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/thought/record', $thought )
        ->assertStatus(422);
}
```

When I uncomment the `dd(json_encode("[{'id': 2000, 'intensity': 100, 'new_intensity': 20}]"));` I get: `""[{'id': 2000, 'intensity': 100, 'new_intensity': 20}]""`

**Test message**

> 1. Tests\Feature\UserThoughtRecordsTest::a_thought_records_json_emotions_must_be_integers
>    Expected status code 422 but received 201.
>    Failed asserting that 422 is identical to 201.

How do I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode()` will return `null` if you if you use single quotes in a double quote string like so:

`json_decode("[{'id': 2000, 'intensity': 100, 'new_intensity': 20}]")`

What you need to do is use single quotes for the string and double quotes for the JSON like so:

`json_decode('[{"id": 2000, "intensity": 100, "new_intensity": 20}]', true)`

Laravels validation can then validate your request as a PHP array.